# Splitting a String of a large negative number and putting it into a LinkedList

Tags: java, string, parsing, integer

This is my method, but I get a NumberFormatException for input "-" when I try to run it for a negative number.

```
public newObj(String s)
{
    list = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    String[] splitted = s.split("\\d");

    int[] ints = new int[splitted.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < splitted.length - 1; i++) {
        ints[i] = Integer.parseInt(splitted[i]);
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < ints.length - 1; j++) {
        list.add(ints[j]);
    }

}
```

My input string is just a number like "-123456" or "12345". Positive numbers work, but I can't get negatives to work.

For my negative input string, I want my list to be something like [-1,-2,-3,-4,-5,-6].

Comment: (per Ren8888) "What is your input string?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it will split number by a a numeric pattern so if you have `-123`

For example:

```
String str = "-123";
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(str.split("\\d")));
```

**output**

```
[-]
```

and `-`  is not parsable to `int`

**from comments:**

for input like `-123456` op wants to make it positive number

You can do it by

```
Math.abs(Integer.parseInt(inputString))
```

let it parse negative number and then you can get its absolute value using [`Math.abs()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#abs%28int%29)

**further from comments**

op wants to split each digit and apply sign, you can do something like

```
    String str = "-123";
    int numbers[] = null;
    int characterIndex = 0;
    boolean isNegative = false;

    if (str.trim().startsWith("-")) {
        characterIndex = 1;
        isNegative = true;
        numbers = new int[str.length() - 1];
    } else {
        numbers = new int[str.length()];

    }

    for (int numIndex = 0; characterIndex < str.length(); characterIndex++, numIndex++) {
        numbers[numIndex] = Integer.parseInt(str.substring(characterIndex, characterIndex + 1));
        if (isNegative) {
            numbers[numIndex] = -1 * numbers[numIndex];
        }

    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(numbers));
```

**Note:** error handling is left on you

Comment: When I add it to the list, could I just skip the "-" and then multiply every number by  -1 when I add it to the list?

Comment: what is your input string sample look like ?

Comment: A sample would be "-123456", but I would also have to handle positives like "123456"

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean that I want to convert it to a positive. I meant that the input string could either be positive or negative. As of right now, my code works for positive numbers, but I can't get it to work for negatives. I think I have a solution to my problem, but I just don't know a way to parse AND split a String that is a negative number into separate negative integers.

Comment: You can simply parse negative number the same way, for example `Integer.parseInt("-123")` will return to `int` `-123`

Comment: Ex) I want split -123456 into [-1 -2 -3 -4 -5 -6]